# Select certain values and sort alphabetically in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I select on certain values and sort them alphabetically using ES6.
The current codes defines a constant. I wanted to know if I could manipulate this data without having to create a new constant with just the values I need.

```
export const names = {
John: 'John',
Mike: 'Mike',
David: 'David',
Chris: 'Chris'
};
```

Return only Chris and David.

Chris

David

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you attempt this yourself. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will be glad to help.

Comment: Why are you using an object for this instead of an array? it seems like all the values are the same as the keys

Comment: @ControlAltDel this is in an existing application. I'm just trying to work with what is there.

Comment: @WaisKamal Thank you, but I have been attempting. That is why I posted here.

Comment: You must share your attempts so we can know what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const names = {
  John: 'John',
  Mike: 'Mike',
  David: 'David',
  Chris: 'Chris',
};

const searchNames = (args, search) => {
  const arr = Object.values(args);
  const result = arr.filter(n => {
    return search.includes(n);
  });
  return result.sort().join('\n');
};

searchNames(names, ['David', 'Chris']);
// returns: Chris  
//          David
```

Not the most elegant, but it works. It would be easier to start with an array instead of an object. It doesn't seem like the object is necessary since the keys and values are identical. Nonetheless, this is a pretty easy task with an array. I converted the obj to an array containing only the values. Then created a new array 
filtering out the names we wanted, returned that array sorted alphabetically and in a string format. The `('\n')` in the return statement is just delimiting the elements of the array by a new line, since that's the format you showed. But that can be changed to anything, if you don't need the names to be on separate lines.

Just to clarify, as per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description), const *can* be used here:

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can manipulate this data, have a look on how const works in javascrips.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

```js
const names = {
John: 'John',
Mike: 'Mike',
David: 'David',
Chris: 'Chris'
};

console.log(names.John);

names.John = 'noJohn';

console.log(names.John);
```

Comment: You have a good point, but this is not an answer to the question.